Dockerize an app that requires specific hostnames and virtualhosts
We currently have a LAMP stack app that is composed of 7 different parts/websites that share some databases and files. But every website has a specific domain and virtualhost that points to a specific directory in the app.
How can i translate this in docker so that it is the easiest to share and reinstall for new developpers ?
We are currently using homestead/vagrant but would like to move to docker.
In Homestead the websites are defined as follow and this part is working correctly :
- map: website1.test
  to: /home/vagrant/code/website1
  php: "8.1"
  type: "apache"
- map: website2.test
  to: /home/vagrant/code/website2
  php: "8.1"
  type: "apache"
...

Thanks a lot,

The host-based routing will be hard to set up (did you have to sudo $EDITOR /etc/hosts? you'll have to repeat this in every environment).  Can you make the host names configurable, and/or use path-based routing?  If there are calls between services within the container environment (website1 directly calls website2) then the container environment will provide its own DNS setup, but the host names will not be the specific ones you've written down.

Yes we had to edit the hosts files, but it was automated on install because the lines are always the same, the vagrant machine IP was hardcoded and specific to this app (192.168.10.10 website1.test   192.168.10.10 website2.test  ...)
This app can't work with path based routing, but the hostnames could be configurables (already the case between the dev and prod env).
The apps don't need to call each others but have a few common files/services (shared code/conf/db/search/...)
